# MS Excel: Set value in a unique id column to value 'B',if multiple records for same id also contain value 'B' in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 worksheets with a parent-child like structure.

Worksheet 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzouK.png)

In worksheet 1, cid column is a unique id column. 'A or B?' column's value is depended on occurrence of A and B values in worksheet 2.

Worksheet 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8HvJ.png)

Here, multiple records are associated with Cid and text value column has values A or B.

My question is, for records associated to an id in worksheet 2, if text value contains value 'B' at least once, then the same id in worksheet 1 must be marked as 'B'.

How do I proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=if(countifs(sheet2!a:a, a2, sheet2!b:b, "B"), "B", if(countifs(sheet2!a:a, a2, sheet2!b:b, "A"), "A", text(,)))
```